# have search button flloat at the buttom on view and not pass it's container

Tags: css

this is the codepen

https://codepen.io/rad-mej/pen/qBKedwB

So, I have a search menu fixed at the left, and I have data on the right.
In the search menu I have search button. I like the search button to be fixed to the buttom of view, and when the user scroll down , the button stick to the end of the menu and pass it.
I hope i'm clear, is that possible?

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.filter-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  max-height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid DarkKhaki;
}

.search-button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div>menu and other content></div>
<div> some other content</div>
</br>
</br>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="filter-menu">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
    <button type="" value="Search" class="search-button">Search</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    a alias quos, numquam iusto unde iste, labore consectetur autem doloremque, ab itaque? Quos corporis voluptatem quis cum fugiat deleniti, sed corrupti vero quod praesentium facilis. Rem illo commodi quisquam temporibus, facilis blanditiis sequi alias
    perferendis optio. Numquam quisquam aspernatur enim adipisci repellat perspiciatis ab debitis consequatur facere. Dolorum qui ad laborum enim perspiciatis quia labore, esse maxime. Qui provident quisquam quos repellendus, consequuntur ipsa consectetur
    vero, dolor excepturi voluptatem laboriosam saepe. Amet, doloribus. Architecto excepturi ad Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt error repellat libero, inventore quidem nihil eaque soluta officiis quod ex consequatur nemo
    harum est natus ratione ullam. Sapiente tenetur distinctio laudantium culpa, soluta saepe eveniet quis nulla, dicta vel similique recusandae fuga dolorem quos nobis veritatis! Quae eveniet quasi praesentium repellat, eaque libero ea distinctio ipsum,
    non veritatis mollitia natus perspiciatis? Quibusdam tempore culpa corrupti cum quia alias quos, numquam iusto unde iste, labore consectetur autem doloremque, ab itaque? Quos corporis voluptatem quis cum fugiat deleniti, sed corrupti vero quod praesentium
    facilis. Rem illo commodi quisquam temporibus, facilis blanditiis sequi alias perferendis optio. Numquam quisquam aspernatur enim adipisci repellat perspiciatis ab debitis consequatur facere. Dolorum qui ad laborum enim perspiciatis quia labore, esse
    maxime. Qui provident quisquam quos repellendus, consequuntur ipsa consectetur vero, dolor excepturi voluptatem laboriosam saepe. Amet, doloribus. Architecto excepturi ad nam, facilis dolore similique blanditiis fugit consequuntur ducimus est, praesentium
    necessitatibus ipsa ea. Animi eos nobis expedita distinctio commodi laborum obcaecati, ipsam doloribus officia tenetur! Unde rem dolor ducimus tempora dicta et perferendis, suscipit consectetur officia deleniti ullam dolorem nesciunt fugiat aliquid
    fugit sit. Cumque molestiae quae beatae totam accusamus officiis quam deserunt sequi aliquid voluptatum optio quod asperiores dolore maxime qui, repudiandae exercitationem obcaecati est repellat aliquam magni? Porro quod necessitatibus, excepturi
    repellat nesciunt doloremque sequi rem voluptatem quia, ipsum ut ducimus, accusamus fugit vitae est praesentium? Doloremque minima eligendi odit consequatur cumque sapiente ullam. Distinctio officiis ab facere cumque, unde perspiciatis? Quis omnis,
    qui ut aspernatur natus temporibus dolore cumque sequi iusto facilis itaque repellat, architecto optio? Cupiditate quaerat, similique eaque nemo explicabo iste! Repudiandae non ullam vitae tenetur ipsa vero totam soluta nostrum, quibusdam quae atque
    labore id saepe ad optio error, ex similique laboriosam maiores facere. Est ullam ipsa natus molestias perspiciatis doloribus maiores velit voluptate? Exercitationem officiis corrupti voluptate sapiente dolorem quo, iure cum alias, quaerat, hic vitae
    ea maxime blanditiis eos eius dolorum neque qui nulla architecto fugiat doloribus? Fugiat rerum et officia? Atque doloremque culpa accusantium enim quasi? Totam eos fugiat adipisci quibusdam quae tenetur, velit dignissimos sint pariatur nesciunt qui
    dolorum expedita, consequatur amet unde aut nostrum omnis perspiciatis praesentium. Excepturi quos, similique alias mollitia aliquid quod animi nemo itaque doloribus, inventore, doloremque distinctio neque. Doloremque magnam molestias architecto,
    odio quia ipsa omnis at nesciunt. Tempora officiis assumenda distinctio dolorem soluta nisi deleniti laboriosam, vitae corporis praesentium mollitia culpa voluptate, impedit quibusdam nostrum in provident suscipit magni doloremque asperiores autem,
    velit et animi vel. Alias, molestiae, nesciunt blanditiis nobis ipsam consequuntur, ipsa quod officia quidem cumque voluptas reiciendis est. Fuga officiis quia perspiciatis ducimus odit sed dolorem veritatis esse cum a recusandae quam, quaerat soluta
    eveniet dicta quisquam impeda alias quos, numquam iusto unde iste, labore consectetur autem doloremque, ab itaque? Quos corporis voluptatem quis cum fugiat deleniti, sed corrupti vero quod praesentium facilis. Rem illo commodi quisquam temporibus,
    facilis blanditiis sequi alias perferendis optio. Numquam quisquam aspernatur enim adipisci repellat perspiciatis ab debitis consequatur facere. Dolorum qui ad laborum enim perspiciatis quia labore, esse maxime. Qui provident quisquam quos repellendus,
    consequuntur ipsa consectetur vero, dolor excepturi voluptatem laboriosam saepe. Amet, doloribus. Architecto excepturi ad it corrupti sunt blanditiis harum sequi? Veniam sint laboriosam, asperiores corrupti dolorem sit a alias quos, numquam iusto
    unde iste, labore consectetur autem doloremque, ab itaque? Quos corporis voluptatem quis cum fugiat deleniti, sed corrupti vero quod praesentium facilis. Rem illo commodi quisquam temporibus, facilis blanditiis sequi alias perferendis optio. Numquam
    quisquam aspernatur enim adipisci repellat perspiciatis ab debitis consequatur facere. Dolorum qui ad laborum enim perspiciatis quia labore, esse maxime. Qui provident quisquam quos repellendus, consequuntur ipsa consectetur vero, dolor excepturi
    voluptatem laboriosam saepe. Amet, doloribus. Architecto excepturi ad tempore accusamus consequuntur minima eaque perspiciatis praesentium, necessitatibus quo delectus deleniti aliquam iste, deserunt magnam. Vitae blanditiis tempore quo facere vel,
    at illo deleniti sapiente quos ipsam porro a quis perspiciatis aspernatur ea provident iusto, neque dolorum aliquid atque. Tenetur sunt nemo unde enim repudiandae earum, ducimus atque sit doloremque voluptates quam in voluptas fugiat et possimus,
    dolor iure. Quos, ratione. Facere consequuntur id qui sunt ipsa, eius veniam quae mollitia, voluptatum corrupti dolore voluptas aspernatur tempore adipisci nisi doloremque delectus harum, quas quidem? Autem, dolores labore officiis maiores animi eos
    ea necessitatibus doloremque, praesentium in voluptatibus. Corporis velit quaerat, aliquid quos assumenda, in explicabo accusamus ut amet sequi obcaecati soluta voluptas maxime. Corrupti ab dolorem nam maxime alias voluptate eveniet laudantium soluta
    animi a alias quos, numquam iusto unde iste, labore consectetur autem doloremque, ab itaque? Quos corporis voluptatem quis cum fugiat deleniti, sed corrupti vero quod praesentium facilis. Rem illo commodi quisquam temporibus, facilis blanditiis sequi
    alias perferendis optio. Numquam quisquam aspernatur enim adipisci repellat perspiciatis ab debitis consequatur facere. Dolorum qui ad laborum enim perspiciatis quia labore, esse maxime. Qui provident quisquam quos repellendus, consequuntur ipsa consectetur
    vero, dolor excepturi voluptatem laboriosam saepe. Amet, doloribus. Architecto excepturi ad provident asperiores placeat ipsum esse voluptatibus quam, consectetur ipsa dolores explicabo tempora illo fugit quos pariatur velit cupiditate. Consequuntur
    dolorem quos voluptatum fuga? Perspiciatis facilis ipsam at doloremque animi commodi, quas consectetur aperiam, minima sunt quae! Eos expedita nihil nesciunt. Magnam beatae explicabo aperiam tenetur harum delectus hic voluptatum reiciendis, laboriosam
    saepe perspiciatis blanditiis eius ad fuga deserunt ducimus ratione quis aspernatur mollitia maiores neque numquam! Nesciunt at, perferendis corporis ipsam sint recusandae labore sed vero veniam nobis rem sunt laudantium placeat nemo explicabo modi
    ducimus deserunt assumenda aliquam ratione atque. Corrupti veritatis hic dignissimos ipsa, necessitatibus cumque iste assumenda odio, consectetur autem sint quas quod numquam perferendis fugit, rem cum. Porro totam ea delectus expedita unde, architecto
    laborum eius similique quis libero eaque mollitia odio adipisci officiis facilis vero. In soluta dolorum ex, ratione voluptatibus perspiciatis, cumque eligendi dolorem facere cum ipsum pariatur molestias omnis ipsa! Delectus provident quasi, eum quisquam
    accusantium fugit? Maxime quam quod in autem ipsam asperiores dolorem, maiores consequuntur repellat officia amet ad delectus, aliquam facere ab! Facilis, itaque magni! Doloremque repellat incidunt magni, assumenda est delectus nemo distinctio reiciendis
    quis minus ex mollitia vero? Accusantium maiores architecto illo corrupti voluptate nre. Quos, ratione. Facere consequuntur id qui sunt ipsa, eius veniam quae mollitia, voluptatum corrupti dolore voluptas aspernatur tempore adipisci nisi doloremque
    delectus harum, quas quidem? Autem, dolores labore officiis maiores animi eos ea necessitatibus doloremque, praesentium in voluptatibus. Corporis velit quaerat, aliquid quos assumenda, in explicabo accusamus ut amet sequi obcaecati soluta voluptas
    maxime. Corrupti ab dolorem nam maxime alias voluptate eveniet laudantium soluta animi a alias quos, numquam iusto unde iste, labore consectetur autem doloremque, ab itaque? Quos corporis voluptatem quis cum fugiat deleniti, sed corrupti vero quod
    praesentium facilis. Rem illo commodi quisquam temporibus, facilis blanditiis sequi alias perferendis optio. Numquam quisquam aspernatur enim adipisci repellat perspiciatis ab debitis consequatur facere. Dolorum qui ad laborum enim perspiciatis quia
    labore, esse maxime. Qui provident quisquam quos repellendus, consequuntur ipsa consectetur vero, dolor excepturi voluptatem laboriosam saepe. Amet, doloribus. Architecto excepturi ad provident asperiorre. Quos, ratione. Facere consequuntur id qui
    sunt ipsa, eius veniam quae mollitia, voluptatum corrupti dolore voluptas aspernatur tempore adipisci nisi doloremque delectus harum, quas quidem? Autem, dolores labore officiis maiores animi eos ea necessitatibus doloremque, praesentium in voluptatibus.
    Corporis velit quaerat, aliquid quos assumenda, in explicabo accusamus ut amet sequi obcaecati soluta voluptas maxime. Corrupti ab dolorem nam maxime alias voluptate eveniet laudantium soluta animi a alias quos, numquam iusto unde iste, labore consectetur
    autem doloremque, ab itaque? Quos corporis voluptatem quis cum fugiat deleniti, sed corrupti vero quod praesentium facilis. Rem illo commodi quisquam temporibus, facilis blanditiis sequi alias perferendis optio. Numquam quisquam aspernatur enim adipisci
    repellat perspiciatis ab debitis consequatur facere. Dolorum qui ad laborum enim perspiciatis quia labore, esse maxime. Qui provident quisquam quos repellendus, consequuntur ipsa consectetur vero, dolor excepturi voluptatem laboriosam saepe. Amet,
    doloribus. Architecto excepturi ad provident asperioron voluptates totam iusto tenetur, sunt, ullam nobis soluta quo repellendus adipisci, explicabo ducimus in sre. Quosre. Quos, ratione. Facere consequuntur id qui sunt ipsa, eius veniam quae mollitia,
    voluptatum corrupti dolore voluptas aspernatur tempore adipisci nisi doloremque delectus harum, quas quidem? Autem, dolores labore officiisre. Quos, ratione. Facere consequuntur id qui sunt ipsa, eius veniam quae mollitia, voluptatum corrupti dolore
    voluptas aspernatur tempore adipisci nisi doloremque delectus harum, quas quidem? Autem, dolores labore officiis maiores animi eos ea necessitatibus doloremque, praesentium in voluptatibus. Corporis velit quaerat, aliquid quos assumenda, in explicabo
    accusamus ut amet sequi obcaecati soluta voluptas maxime. Corrupti ab dolorem nam maxime alias voluptate eveniet laudantium soluta animi a alias quos, numquam iusto unde iste, labore consectetur autem doloremque, ab itaque? Quos corporis voluptatem
    quis cum fugiat deleniti, sed corrupti vero quod praesentium facilis. Rem illo commodi quisquam temporibus, facilis blanditiis sequi alias perferendis optio. Numquam quisquam aspernatur enim adipisci repellat perspiciatis ab debitis consequatur facere.
    Dolorum qui ad laborum enim perspiciatis quia labore, esse maxime. Qui provident quisquam quos repellendus, consequuntur ipsa consectetur vero, dolor excepturi voluptatem laboriosam saepe. Amet, doloribus. Architecto excepturi ad provident asperior
    maiores animi eos ea necessitatibus doloremque, praesentium in voluptatibus. Corporis velit quaerat, aliquid quos assumenda, in explicabo accusamus ut amet sequi obcaecati soluta voluptas maxime. Corrupti ab dolorem nam maxime alias voluptate eveniet
    laudantium soluta animi a alias quos, numquam iusto unde iste, labore consectetur autem doloremque, ab itaque? Quos corporis voluptatem quis cum fugiat deleniti, sed corrupti vero quod praesentium facilis. Rem illo commodi quisquam temporibus, facilis
    blanditiis sequi alias perferendis optio. Numquam quisquam aspernatur enim adipisci repellat perspiciatis ab debitis consequatur facere. Dolorum qui ad laborum enim perspiciatis quia labore, esse maxime. Qui provident quisquam quos repellendus, consequuntur
    ipsa consectetur vero, dolor excepturi voluptatem laboriosam saepe. Amet, doloribus. Architecto excepturi ad provident asperiorre. Quos, ratione. Facere consequuntur id qui sunt ipsa, eius veniam quae mollitia, voluptatum corrupti dolore voluptas
    aspernatur tempore adipisci nisi doloremque delectus harum, quas quidem? Autem, dolores labore officiis maiores animi eos ea necessitatibus doloremque, praesentium in voluptatibus. Corporis velit quaerat, aliquid quos assumenda, in explicabo accusamus
    ut amet sequi obcaecati soluta voluptas maxime. Corrupti ab dolorem nam maxime alias voluptate eveniet laudantium soluta animi a alias quos, numquam iusto unde iste, labore consectetur autem doloremque, ab itaque? Quos corporis voluptatem quis cum
    fugiat deleniti, sed corrupti vero quod praesentium facilis. Rem illo commodi quisquam temporibus, facilis blanditiis sequi alias perferendis optio. Numquam quisquam aspernatur enim adipisci repellat perspiciatis ab debitis consequatur facere. Dolorum
    qui ad laborum enim perspiciatis quia labore, esse maxime. Qui provident quisquam quos repellendus, consequuntur ipsa consectetur vero, dolor excepturi voluptatem laboriosam saepe. Amet, doloribus. Architecto excepturi ad provident asperior, ratione.
    Facere consequuntur id qui sunt ipsa, eius veniam quae mollitia, voluptatum corrupti dolore voluptas aspernatur tempore adipisci nisi doloremque delectus harum, quas quidem? Autem, dolores labore officiis maiores animi eos ea necessitatibus doloremque,
    praesentium in voluptatibus. Corporis velit quaerat, aliquid quos assumenda, in explicabo accusamus ut amet sequi obcaecati soluta voluptas maxime. Corrupti ab dolorem nam maxime alias voluptate eveniet laudantium soluta animi a alias quos, numquam
    iusto unde iste, labore consectetur autem doloremque, ab itaque? Quos corporis voluptatem quis cum fugiat deleniti, sed corrupti vero quod praesentium facilis. Rem illo commodi quisquam temporibus, facilis blanditiis sequi alias perferendis optio.
    Numquam quisquam aspernatur enim adipisci repellat perspiciatis ab debitis consequatur facere. Dolorum qui ad laborum enim perspiciatis quia labore, esse maxime. Qui provident quisquam quos repellendus, consequuntur ipsa consectetur vero, dolor excepturi
    voluptatem laboriosam saepe. Amet, doloribus. Architecto excepturi ad provident asperiorre. Quos, ratione. Facere consequuntur id qui sunt ipsa, eius veniam quae mollitia, voluptatum corrupti dolore voluptas aspernatur tempore adipisci nisi doloremque
    delectus harum, quas quidem? Autem, dolores labore officiis maiores animi eos ea necessitatibus doloremque, praesentire. Quos, ratione. Facere consequuntur id qui sunt ipsa, eius veniam quae mollitia, voluptatum corrupti dolore voluptas aspernatur
    tempore adipisci nisi doloremque delectus harum, quas quidem? Autem, dolores labore officiis maiores animi eos ea necessitatibus doloremque, praesentium in voluptatibus. Corporis velit quaerat, aliquid quos assumenda, in explicabo accusamus ut amet
    sequi obcaecati soluta voluptas maxime. Corrupti ab dolorem nam maxime alias voluptate eveniet laudantium soluta animi a alias quos, numquam iusto unde iste, labore consectetur autem doloremque, ab itaque? Quos corporis voluptatem quis cum fugiat
    deleniti, sed corrupti vero quod praesentium facilis. Rem illo commodi quisquam temporibus, facilis blanditiis sequi alias perferendis optio. Numquam quisquam aspernatur enim adipisci repellat perspiciatis ab debitis consequatur facere. Dolorum qui
    ad laborum enim perspiciatis quia labore, esse maxime. Qui provident quisquam quos repellendus, consequuntur ipsa consectetur vero, dolor excepturi voluptatem laboriosam saepe. Amet, doloribus. Architecto excepturi ad provident asperiorum in voluptatibus.
    Corporis velit quaerat, aliquid quos assumenda, in explicabo accusamus ut amet sequi obcaecati soluta voluptas maxime. Corrupti ab dolorem nam maxime alias voluptate eveniet laudantium soluta animi a alias quos, numquam iusto unde iste, labore consectetur
    autem doloremque, ab itaque? Quos corporis voluptatem quis cum fugiat deleniti, sed corrupti vero quod praesentium facilis. Rem illo commodi quisquam temporibus, facilis blanditiis sequi alias perferendis optio. Numquam quisquam aspernatur enim adipisci
    repellat perspiciatis ab debitis consequatur facere. Dolorum qui ad laborum enim perspiciatis quia labore, esse maxime. Qui provident quisquam quos repellendus, consequuntur ipsa consectetur vero, dolor excepturi voluptatem laboriosam saepe. Amet,
    doloribus. Architecto excepturi ad provident asperiorint. Accusamus, corrupti et dolorum necessitatibus, veniam ex obcaecati deserunt soluta fuga adipisci tempora unde consequatur quibusdam in praesentium possimus, aspernatur architecto sunt aperiam
    eius? Tempora maiores temporibus earum facere quaerat deserunt minima re. Quos, ratione. Facere consequuntur id qui sunt ipsa, eius veniam quae mollitia, voluptatum corrupti dolore voluptas aspernatur tempore adipisci nisi doloremque delectus harum,
    quas quidem? Autem, dolores labore officiis maiores animi eos ea necessitatibus doloremque, praesentium in voluptatibus. Corporis velit quaerat, aliqure. Quos, ratione. Facere consequuntur id qui sunt ipsa, eius veniam quae mollitia, voluptatum corrupti
    dolore voluptas aspernatur tempore adipisci nisi doloremque delectus harum, quas quidem? Autem, dolores labore officiis maiores animi eos ea necessitatibus doloremque, praesentium in voluptatibus. Corporis velit quaerat, aliquid quos assumenda, in
    explicabo accusamus ut amet sequi obcaecati soluta voluptas maxime. Corrupti ab dolorem nam maxime alias voluptate eveniet laudantium soluta animi a alias quos, numquam iusto unde iste, labore consectetur autem doloremque, ab itaque? Quos corporis
    voluptatem quis cum fugiat deleniti, sed corrupti vero quod praesentium facilis. Rem illo commodi quisquam temporibus, facilis blanditiis sequi alias perferendis optio. Numquam quisquam aspernatur enim adipisci rre. Quos, ratione. Facere consequuntur
    id qui sunt ipsa, eius veniam quae mollitia, voluptatum corrupti dolore voluptas aspernatur tempore adipisci nisi doloremque delectus harum, quas quidem? Autem, dolores labore officiis maiores animi eos ea necessitatibus doloremque, praesentium in
    voluptatibus. Corporis velit quaerat, aliquid quos assumenda, in explicabo accusamus ut amet sequi obcaecati soluta voluptas maxime. Corrupti ab dolorem nam maxime alias voluptate eveniet laudantium soluta animi a alias quos, numquam iusto unde iste,
    labore consectetur autem doloremque, ab itaque? Quos corporis voluptatem quis cum fugiat deleniti, sed corrupti vero quod praesentium facilis. Rem illo commodi quisquam temporibus, facilis blanditiis sequi alias perferendis optio. Numquam quisquam
    aspernatur enim adipisci repellat perspiciatis ab debitis consequatur facere. Dolorum qui ad laborum enim perspiciatis quia labore, esse maxime. Qui provident quisquam quos repellendus, consequuntur ipsa consectetur vero, dolor excepturi voluptatem
    laboriosam saepe. Amet, doloribus. Architecto excepturi ad provident asperiorepellat perspiciatis ab debitis consequatur facere. Dolorum qui ad laborum enim perspiciatis quia labore, esse maxime. Qui provident quisquam quos repellendus, consequuntur
    ipsa consectetur vero, dolor excepturi voluptatem laboriosam saepe. Amet, doloribus. Architecto excepturi ad provident asperiorid quos assumenda, in explicabo accusamus ut amet sequi obcaecati soluta voluptas maxime. Corrupti ab dolorem nam maxime
    alias voluptate eveniet laudantium soluta animi a alias quos, numquam iusto unde iste, labore consectetur autem doloremque, ab itaque? Quos corporis voluptatem quis cum fugiat deleniti, sed corrupti vero quod praesentium facilis. Rem illo commodi
    quisquam temporibus, facilis blanditiis sequi alias perferendis optio. Numquam quisquam aspernatur enim adipisci repellat perspiciatis ab debitis consequatur facere. Dolorum qui ad laborum enim perspiciatis quia labore, esse maxime. Qui provident
    quisquam quos repellendus, consequuntur ipsa consectetur vero, dolor excepturi voluptatem laboriosam saepe. Amet, doloribus. Architecto excepturi ad provident asperiorat voluptatem reprehenderit? Eos, provident! Maiores dolor pariatur totam! Laboriosam
    quam laborum rerum accusamus, recusandae quaerat dolores numquam saepe eos obcaecati. Cupiditate veritatis, culpa vel dolores fugiat reprehenderit, reiciendis quas quaerat veniam vitae totam assumenda temporibus? Neque ipsam eos harum porro atque
    in beatae incidunt labore rerum magni reiciendis, itaque, veniam rem sequi nesciunt saepe provident tempore voluptatibus aperiam expedita quisquam explicabo fugiat molestiae debitis. Delectus error quibusdam laborum consequuntur. Esse saepe natus
    consequatur quasi nobis reprehenderit reiciendis eius neque sunt aspernatur similique laboriosam ad eligendi fugit dolorem nesciunt alias officiis dicta cum, ducimus quod? Eaque sit cumque quasi exercitationem beatae omnis natus asperiores animi,
    molestiae iste eveniet id, nihil repellat excepturi officiis, praesentium laboriosam ducimus tempora. Tempore, eligendi? Placeat iste ut, asperiores et minima officiis provident, obcaecati officia labore quod fuga corrupti ex vero tempore tenetur
    non unde ullam atque. Voluptatum rem quae dolorum officia officiis, cupiditate ipsam, reiciendis accusamus provident recusandae vel earum et dignissimos quis facere sit. Ab, consequuntur distinctio beatae mollitia magnam tempore fugiat enim incidunt.
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you want the whole menu to be sticky?

Answer (score 0):

It's done by making positin: sticky  , bottom:20px;
but be cearful to do not have any overflow attribute on any parent of the search btn